# In the documentation of Artifactory, what is the value of `<public context>` for configuring a ssl reverse proxy under /webapp

Tags: java, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, artifactory

I want to deploy artifactory behind a ssl public nginx proxy.

I have read the documentation and tried many configuration.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+NGINX

I can't be sure for the value of `<public context>`.

My artifactory is accessible under `http://localhost:31937/webapp/#/home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public context is what you want users to see when they access your Artifactory instance through the reverse proxy. It is not at all related to how your current Artifactory instance it setup. If you want the URLs to look like this:

1. http://my-reverse-proxy-url/**artifactory**/webapp/#/home
   OR
2. http://my-reverse-proxy-url/webapp/#/home

For 1, the public context is artifactory. For option 2, the public context is left blank.